# Cannot open Word or Powerpoint in browser

Tags: word, office-web-apps, powerpoint, sharepoint-server

We have SharePoint 2016 on premise.  In our document libraries, most are set to "Use the server default (Open in the browser)" selection for the default open behavior.

[image]

Up until about a week ago, all documents opened as expected in the online method (Word Online, Powerpoint Online, etc.).  Now we are having an issue with Word and Powerpoint files not opening in the browser.  We are getting the following error -

[image]

[image]

What what would cause this to happen?

Let me know if additional information is needed for troubleshooting

UPDATE - Now Word Online is working as expected but PowerPoint and Excel are not working - the PowerPoint error is consistent with the above error but the Excel error looks like this -

[image]

Comment: Does this happen on all machines? With all different users? In all libraries? What happens if you switch the default behaviour to "Client Application", or to "Open in Browser" , rather than the Server  Default? Are you able to trade that error ID in the LOGS folder in your SharePoint server(s)?

Comment: Yes this is consistent on all machines, with all users, in all libraries.  My work around is to change the default to open in the app as that will launch it in the app.  The odd thing is that no matter what the library settings is, when I click the ellipsis and select "open in Powerpoint Online", it will launch a new tab and open in the online browser window.

Comment: I am not familiar with the "trade that error ID in the LOGS folder in your SharePoint Server(s)?" so I cannot answer that question